# Using ConfigureAwait

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Please take a look at following two methods. The first function **GetQuoteImageContent** is calling **GetFileHeadersByDirectory** to return a list of FileVM objects. However if i return the first function with :

```
return await fileTasks.GetFileHeadersByDirectory(imageLibraryDirectory, false,
                                                 "/quotecontents/").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

then it runs fine but because I need to do some processing on returned value so when I am trying to assign it to a variable:

```
IEnumerable<FileVM> images = await fileTasks.GetFileHeadersByDirectory(
                                             imageLibraryDirectory, false,
                                             "/quotecontents/").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

it is falling out of the function without returning anything.
Please could somebody point out the error in my calling mechanism? In the end , I want to get hold of the collection **IEnumerable< FileVM >** to do some processing over it. Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<FileVM>> GetQuoteImageContent(string quoteId)
{
    IFileTasks fileTasks = new FileTasks();
    string imageLibraryDirectory = string.Format("quotecontents/{0}", quoteId.Split('/')[1]);
    IEnumerable<FileVM> images = await fileTasks.GetFileHeadersByDirectory(imageLibraryDirectory, false, "/quotecontents/").ConfigureAwait(false);

     return images;           
}

// This is 2nd async method which queries database to return list of files
public async Task<IEnumerable<FileVM>> GetFileHeadersByDirectory(string directory, bool recursive, string rootDirectory = "")
{
    using (var fileSession = TasksManager.CreateTemporaryFSSession())
    {
        var fileQuery = fileSession.Query().OnDirectory(directory, recursive);

        var fileHeaders = await fileQuery.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var fileVMs = ConvertToFileVM(fileHeaders, rootDirectory);

        return fileVMs;
    }
}
```

Comment: *it is falling out of the function without returning anything.* What does that mean? If you mean the method is yielding execution control back to the calling method, then that's what it should be doing.

Comment: The control returns to the point from where I am calling GetQuoteImageContent

Comment: That's how `await` works. It will return back to `GetQuoteImageContent` once it finished the async method execution (running its continuation).

Comment: It doesn't return inside GetQuoteImageContent rather it gets to the point from where I have made a call to GetQuoteImageContent

Comment: How are you calling `GetQuoteImageContent`?

Comment: I thought a call like this would fetch me list of image. var images =  GetQuoteImageContent(quoteId).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: Are you not awaiting on `GetQuoteImageContent`?

Comment: No not awaiting. Is that the reason it is failing ?

Comment: And what are you doing with your `images` variable? Could you please add that code to the question?

Comment: Here is what i am trying to do: ` foreach (FileVM item in images)
           {

               QuoteContent content = new QuoteContent();
               content.Content = item.ContentStream;
                    
               quote.ContentList.Add(content) ;
           }`

Comment: How are you iterating `images` if you're not awating the call? `Task` is not iteratable.

Comment: That is something I am confused about , As I thought that I could get the Images collection inside GetQuoteImageContent and do processing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, i'm understand that you're not awaiting on `GetQuoteImageContent`, and that is why you seem to think your method isn't returning the images.

If you want to iterate the images right after your get, you'll have to `await` on that too:

```
IEnumerable<FileVM> images = await GetQuoteImageContent(quoteId).ConfigureAwait(false);

foreach (var image in images)
{
    // Do something
}
```

If you don't `await`, the compiler will yell at you for trying to iterate something which is not iteratable (Since `Task` doesn't implement `IEnumerable`).

Comment: Yes I realized that all methods in the chain were not using 'await' and therefore asynchronous call was failing. Thanks for your help and consideration.